# Не работает link/scripts

Tags: css, jade, link

Через шаблонизатор пытаюсь подключить css-файл, но при просмотре страницы в браузере, тег в макете есть, однако стили все равно не работают.

В чем проблема?

[Расположение файлов проекта](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYFU5.png)

Comment: При переходе по файлу наверняка 404, гляньте в инспекторе

Answer (score 1):

Проблема исчерпана. Сервер писал на nodejs (express), он не отдавал статику. Исправлена было путем добавления `app.use(express.static('templates'));`
Всем спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен куда `процесятся` ваши `jade` файлы, но могу предположить, что поставив `/ccs/ перед style.css в cover.jade` cможет помочь. Eсли `html` файл находится не в домашней директории, то первый `/` укажет на домашнюю директорию, а `css/` скажет искать в `css` директории.

Седьмая строчка будет выглядеть так:

```
link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/style.css")
```